# add images one by one to elements on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

Here's a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/veKyT/4/).

How can I add an image one by one to a div element in `.area` on click? Whatever image is clicked first, I want it to occupy the first div(leftest) and then the next clicked image will go to the second div.

Jquery:

```
$('.compare').click(function(){
  var getimage = $(this).closest('.box').find('img').attr('src');
  $('#area > div').html('<img src="'+getimage+'"/>') 

});

$(document).on('click','#area > div > img',function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/Crystal_Clear_action_run.png/40px-Crystal_Clear_action_run.png"/>
<input class="compare" type="radio"/>
</div>

<div class="box">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/99/Question_book-new.svg/50px-Question_book-new.svg.png"/>
<input class="compare" type="radio"/>
</div>

<div id="area"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

Comment: This is probably not the way the radio button should be used — you might want to explore using other elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Construct the image and assign an `src` attribute to it
2. Make use of `div:empty:first` selector

Example:

```
$('.compare').click(function(){
    var img = $('<img>');
    img.attr('src', $(this).closest('.box').find('img').attr('src'));
    $('#area').find('div:empty:first').append(img);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aqZ6P/)**

Comment: I want the clicked image to go inside one of the `div`s in the `area`, not all of them.